# facebook4j retrieve different image size from my facebook posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-java-api

i am using facebook4j to load home posts `facebook.getHome()` and i am getting the profile image and the post image as follows:

```
facebook4j.User fromUser = facebook.getUser(fbHomePost.getFrom().getId(), 
new Reading().fields("picture"));
if (fromUser.getPicture() != null)                      
  facebookUserPostDto.setProfileImage(fromUser.getPicture().getURL().toURI().toString());
if (fbHomePost.getPicture() != null)
  facebookUserPostDto.setImageLocation(fbHomePost.getPicture().toURI().toString());
```

all is working well, but the image i am getting from the URLs are small and have low resolution. any idea how to get the "large" images from facebook using facebook4j API? facebook can provide different image sizes [API Reference › Graph API › Pictures](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/)

thanks

Comment: no one ever used facebook4j?

Comment: I have integrated facebook4j, but I am getting duplicate feeds. Can you please help me for this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293540/facebook-feed-integration-with-android-app-feeds-getting-duplicated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got a reply from the facebook4j google group on how to go this
[retrieve different image size from my facebook posts](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/facebook4j/XwOijtguSGs)

Sameeh Harfoush

[Brate](http://www.brate.com)

Answer (score 0):

OK first you have to add **user_photos** to your scope and make sure you are using a valid acces token **NOT a Graph API Explorer Token**

```
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                                      .provider(FacebookApi.class)
                                      .apiKey(apiKey)
                                      .apiSecret(apiSecret)
                                      .callback("xxxx")
                                      .scope("publish_actions,user_photos ")
                                      .build();
```

then try this : (tested)

```
for(Post p : feed){
        System.out.println("********************");
        String type = p.getType();
        System.out.println("type :"+type);
        String idPicVid = p.getObjectId();
        if(type.matches("photo")){
           System.out.println("idPicVid "+idPicVid);
                try{
                    Photo pic = facebook.getPhoto(idPicVid);
                    System.out.println(pic.toString());
                    System.out.println("source "+pic.getSource());
                    System.out.println("picture "+pic.getPicture());
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```